# How can I create a many-to-many relationship with SQLAlchemy using a SQL function?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, geoalchemy2

I want to create a relationship between two models that have `Geometry` columns. For example:

```
from geoalchemy2.types import Geometry
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from myapp import app

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Property(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    street_address = db.Column(db.Text)
    geom = db.Column(Geometry(geometry_type='POINT'))

    service_areas = db.relationship(
        'ServiceArea',
        primaryjoin='ServiceArea.geom.ST_Contains(Geocode.geom)',
        lazy='joined',
        uselist=True,
        viewonly=True,
    )

class ServiceArea (db.Model):
    name = db.Column(db.Text)
    value = db.Column(db.Text)
    geom = db.Column(Geometry(geometry_type='MULTIPOLYGON'))
```

In this example, a `Property` may be associated with many `ServiceArea`s, and a `ServiceArea` may be associated with many properties. However, there's not a secondary table for me to use for the relationship -- it is all determined by the `ST_Contains` function.

Whenever I run this code, I get an `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError` exception telling me to *"Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or are annotated in the join condition with the foreign() annotation."*

When I add `foreign` around the `ServiceArea.geom` (even though it's not a foreign key), I get an error suggesting that I *"Consider using the remote() annotation to accurately mark those elements of the join condition that are on the remote side of the relationship."*

I've tried using `foreign` and `remote` separately as well as together (e.g., `foreign(remote(ServiceArea.geom))` and `remote(foreign(ServiceArea.geom))`) but always get back one of the above errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `Geocode.geom` supposed to be `Property.geom`?

Comment: Did you figure out what the problem was? I'm running into the same issue... @zzzeek

Comment: see the discussion and POC at https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3831/allow-for-funcxyz-to-be-treated-as-a .